# How to get the fuel on board reading on UVdatalink via Honeywell ACARS system?

Tags: fuel, acars, flight-data-monitoring

I would like to find out if anyone has encountered the following issue and how was it rectified.
We are currently seeing the following results on UVdatalink for some of our aircraft that have Honeywell ACARS units installed. 
[image]

We would like to see the following message which we get from Rockwell ACARS units.
[image]

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you call Honeywell directly and ask them this question? We don't provide tech support for products, and your question is highly specialized.

Comment: @RonBeyer People do ask questions that are this detailed on Stack Overflow......   Granted, I'm not sure we have the kind of user base required to answer this question.  Going to Honeywell is probably going to be the more useful course of action.

Comment: @JayCarr each community on stack exchange has its own rules and guidelines. I'm not quite sure tech support is [on topic here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) whereas it is quite sread among stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you guys. I understand that it is a highly specialized question and was being very optimistic for a solution here. We have gone to Honeywell but unfortunately they could not help with the matter.

Comment: @ManuH That's actually a good question for Meta (though I wouldn't worry about it yet, considering this is kind of the first question I've seen like this.)  But I'd like to think Aviation.SE could be a resource for plane owners...not sure if that should include commercial.......  So, yeah, a good topic for Meta perhaps.

Comment: @JayCarr [done](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3072/should-tech-support-be-on-topic). Feel free to comment/edit/answer/....

Comment: @ManuH Excellent, looks like it's generating some consensus, that's what I really like to see ;)